# Transaction management in Promises operations of nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I need to implement transaction management in service layer. Nodejs, sequelize and mysql are the technologies what i am using. All crud operations are called from db layer into service layer. Here i need to do 2 insert operation in service layer by calling from 2 separate db layer. And i have implemented sequelize transaction management in my project. My problem is , i can't manage 2 insert operation under single transaction. Why because, i need to collect some data from the 1st successful insertion. So that i could call "then" operation. When i call then operation the transaction got committed. So how should make it possible.

> common_database_Handler_file

```
this.insertData = function(collectionObject, collectionName) {
    var collection = MODELS[collectionName];
    return collection
      .create(collectionObject);
  };
```

> table1_database_Handler_file

```
this.create = function (data1) {
     return commonHandler.insertData(data1,"table1")
}
```

> table2_database_Handler_file

```
this.create = function (data2) {
     return commonHandler.insertData(data2,"table2")
}
```

> service_layer_file

```
sequelize.transaction(function (t1) {

  //saving data to table1
  this.createUser = function (data1) {
    table1Handler.create(data1)
        .then(function (response) {
           if (response) {
             var data2 = {};
             data2.id = response.id; 

             //saving data to table2
             table2Handler.create(data2)
               .then(function (data2) {
                 console.log("success);
                }


            }
         }
         .catch(error => {
          new Error();
          console.log("Failed");
          }
  }

});
```

Comment: According to the documentation it appears you need to specify the transaction when making queries within it: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html
In your case, you might need to pass the transaction to your handles and include it when making the actual query using sequelize (in your common handler).

Comment: Is there any chance to solve this issue by using promises sequential or any other thing like that.

Comment: It looks like you can create a namespace to avoid having to pass the transaction reference. Check the "Automatically pass transactions to all queries" section on the link I pasted above. After that you just need to return a Promise inside the transaction and `resolve` or `reject` it to commit or rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transactions have to be passed into the operations which you are carrying out in the database handler.

```
this.insertData = function(collectionObject, collectionName, t1) {
    var collection = MODELS[collectionName];
    return collection
      .create(collectionObject, { transaction: t1 });
  };
```

To achieve the above, you can pass the transaction from the service layer to the database layer as a parameter to the function

Also in your above implementation, the transaction is not calling a function, but rather it is just assigning a function. Here is a sample of how it should actually look

```
this.createUser = function(data1) {
    return sequelize.transaction(function (t1) { 
        return firstDBfunction(data1, t1)
            .then(function(response){
               return secondDBFunction(data2 , t1);
            });
    }).then(function(response){
        //transaction successful
    }).catch(function(error){
        //transaction failed, so auto ROLLBACK
    });
}
```

Comment: If i call another select query in between first and second db call with out transaction object, does it effect the current  transaction.

Comment: no, only the sequelize queries where you pass transaction object will be effected.